# A discrete subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ which is Haussdorff is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Question is in the title. Let $X$ be a topological space which is Hausdorff, and let $Y \subset X$ be a subset, so that the induced topology on $Y$ is discrete. Is it then true that $Y$ is closed in $X$?

I have the impression that this is only true if $X$ is locally compact, but I feel like I could be missing something.

Comment: Local compactness does not imply this; as Robert Israel points out, it fails in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Any separable metric space can be embedded into $[0,1]^\omega$, the Hilbert cube. $\Bbb Z$ too. Can the image be closed?

Comment: I don't know what $\omega$ is.

Comment: @mnr You could read $\Bbb N$ here as well, if you prefer.